# how can I use polymer core-animated-pages events?

Tags: core-animation, polymer

I want to use core-animated-page's core-animated-pages-transition-prepare event.
How can I use polymer events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a event listener. give core-animated-pages a id (i am calling it 'animatedPages')

```
  animatedPages.addEventListener('core-animated-pages-transition-prepare', function (e) {});
```

or you could use the declarative method

```
 <core-animated-pages selected="{{selected}}" transitions="slide-from-right" on-core-animated-pages-transition-prepare="{{pagesPrepare}}">
```

then in js

```
 pagesPrepare: function (event) {}
```

hope it helps